# How to use # instead of $ in DB2 query with iBatis

Tags: sql, db2, sql-injection, mybatis, ibatis

I use DB2 with iBatis in my project.

There are many

```
FETCH FRIST $perPg$ ROWS ONLY
```

queries for paging in DaoMap.xml files. But it seems dangerous in case of query injection. so I want to change them using # instead of $, but I can't figure it out.

Functions like `CAST(#perPg# AS INTEGER)` doesn't work on FETCH query. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you try #perPg#

Comment: # wraps variable with ', so it triggers error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to int (and ensure that the value arrived is int) you can try with this:

```
#perPg:BIGINT#
```